# Does my host company have to support the Laravel php framework in order for me to use it?

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I don't know much PHP I am more of an asp.net developer. I created a php application some time ago and I need to perform some improvement to the site but because I didn't use any framework the project is pretty messy. I searched on the web and I read about Laravel. My question is : how to deploy a site using this framework? is like asp.net mvc where you build the project and upload the files and works great! or there are requirements on the host enviroment?

Comment: Here are all the requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#server-requirements. If your server meets the requirements, you can run it on your server the way you run it on your computer. No you don't compile anything, you upload via ftp, or source control, or scp for that matter.

Comment: Which parts of Laravel do you want to use? The queue worker is usually executed by supervisord, something you need to run on the server as a separate service.

Comment: I just want to apply some good mvc to that mess. I don't know nothing about Laravel but I will happily do.

Comment: As long as you install the pre-requisites, it doesn't matter what hosting service you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Laravel's documentation on [installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation)

These are the server requirements for laravel 5.3

1. PHP >= 5.6.4
2. OpenSSL PHP Extension
3. PDO PHP Extension
4. Mbstring PHP Extension
5. Tokenizer PHP Extension
6. XML PHP Extension

Comment: I contacted my host company and they said they support it. I understand now... to build a Laravel application the server need it to be installed. It is like having .net installed to use asp.net.

Comment: Technically you don't need to already have laravel installed, just the correct php installed and those extentions

Answer (score 0):

You also will need .htaccess file in the root of you public_html, like this:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [PT]
</IfModule>
```